# I know why Runtime Exception shouldn't require a try - catch or throws but I want to know how it is designed to not require them?

Tags: java, exception

When I extend from Exception, that requires a throw or catch . I couldn't find anything on the RunTimeException class' code

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html

Comment: It's hardcoded into the language that way.  It's not something in its code.

Comment: @snikit ...in other words: you would have to look at the code for the compiler to find the implementation for the difference.

Comment: ok got it . @Hulk ,

Comment: thanks @Louis Wasserman

Answer (score 6):

This is mandated by the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html) in Section [§ 11.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2):

> The unchecked exception classes ([§11.1.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.1.1)) are exempted from compile-time checking.

§11.1.1 states:

> #### 11.1.1. The Kinds of Exceptions
>
> An exception is represented by an instance of the class `Throwable` (a direct subclass of `Object`) or one of its subclasses.
>
> `Throwable` and all its subclasses are, collectively, the *exception classes*.
>
> The classes `Exception` and `Error` are direct subclasses of `Throwable`:
>
> - `Exception` is the superclass of all the exceptions from which ordinary programs may wish to recover.
>
>   The class `RuntimeException` is a direct subclass of `Exception`. `RuntimeException` is the superclass of all the exceptions which may be thrown for many reasons during expression evaluation, but from which recovery may still be possible.
>
>   `RuntimeException` and all its subclasses are, collectively, the *run-time exception classes*.
> - `Error` is the superclass of all the exceptions from which ordinary programs are not ordinarily expected to recover.
>
>   `Error` and all its subclasses are, collectively, the *error classes*.
>
> The *unchecked exception classes* are the run-time exception classes and the error classes.
>
> The *checked exception classes* are all exception classes other than the unchecked exception classes. That is, the checked exception classes are Throwable and all its subclasses other than RuntimeException and its subclasses and Error and its subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

When you go through the details of Exceptions, it is always stated that:

**Unchecked Exceptions:** under Error and `RuntimeException` classes are unchecked exceptions .

**Checked Exceptions:** Checked exceptions are those which extend Exception class but not Run-time-Exception **or** everything else under `throwable` is checked.

```
         +-----------+
       | Throwable |
               +-----------+
                /         \
       /           \
      +-------+          +-----------+
      | Error |          | Exception |
      +-------+          +-----------+
   /  |  \           / |        \
     \________/   \______/       \
                        +------------------+
unchecked    checked    | RuntimeException |
                +------------------+
                  /   |    |      \
                 \_________________/

                   unchecked
```

When your class extend Exception class, your class is treated as an Unchecked exception and hence the compiler asks you surround it with `try` and a `catch`/ `throws`. 
You can make your class extend `Runtime Exception`. But it is treated as not a good coding practice*[Only if your requirement says otherwise]*

Comment: thanks Jayanath , I knew the reason . I was looking into the code , but I guess its wired into the compiler .